# Transform() not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel and i used transform method to change name of the items with in the data object but it is not working it is showing me same data which replicated the database columns name.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Lessons;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
    use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
    class LessonsController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $lessons= Lessons::all();
            return Response::json([
                'data'=>$lessons->toArray()
            ],200);
        }

        public function show($id)
        {
        $lessons= Lessons::find($id);
        if(! $lessons)
        {
            return Response::json([    
                'error'=>[
                    'message'=>'Lesson not found',
                ]
            ],404); 
        }
        return Response::json([
            'data'=>$lessons->toArray()
        ],200);
    }
    private function transform ($lessons)
    {
        return array_map(function($lesson)
        {
            return [
                'heading'=>$lesson['title'],
                'body'=>$lesson['body']
            ];
        },$lessons->toArray());
    }
}
```

and this is the url i am calling:

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/lessons

and this is the output i'm getting:

```
  {
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Title 1",
      "body": "body 1"
    },
    {
      "title": "title 2",
      "body": "body 2"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 3",
      "body": "body 3"
    },
    {
      "title": "title 4",
      "body": "body 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Bottomline: i want heading instead of title in the output but not getting it. Transform function not working

Comment: I don't see the `transform()` method being used anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass `$lessons` to your `transform()` method.

```
public function index()
{
    $lessons= Lessons::all();
    return Response::json([
        'data'=> $this->transform($lessons)
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, 
just a little ammendment and it worked

Comment: public function index()
    {
     $lessons= Lessons::all();
        return Response::json([
            'data'=> $this->transform($lessons)
        ], 200);

    }

Comment: Oh, yes. I did not notice you were calling `toArray()` inside `transform()`. My bad.